# Operating System Updates fail in AppCenter. Runs for 1 second, stops, and the updates are still pending. (grub related packages held back.)

Tags: updates, appcenter, grub, apt, dependencies

### sudo apt upgrade results in:

"The following packages have been kept back: grub-common grub-pc grub-pc-bin grub2-common shim shim-signed":

```
michael@elementaryOS-phy:/$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  grub-common grub-pc grub-pc-bin grub2-common shim shim-signed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
michael@elementaryOS-phy:/$
```

### Listing upgradable packages:

```
michael@elementaryOS-phy:/$ sudo apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
grub-common/bionic 2.02-2ubuntu8.23+elementary27~ubuntu5.1.7.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.02-2ubuntu8.21+elementary26~ubuntu5.1.7.1]
grub-efi-amd64-signed/bionic 1.167~18.04.5+elementary23~ubuntu5.1.7.1+2.04-1ubuntu44.1.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.93.24+elementary22~ubuntu5.1.7.1+2.02-2ubuntu8.21+elementary26~ubuntu5.1.7.1]
grub-pc/bionic 2.02-2ubuntu8.23+elementary27~ubuntu5.1.7.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.02-2ubuntu8.21+elementary26~ubuntu5.1.7.1]
grub-pc-bin/bionic 2.02-2ubuntu8.23+elementary27~ubuntu5.1.7.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.02-2ubuntu8.21+elementary26~ubuntu5.1.7.1]
grub2-common/bionic 2.02-2ubuntu8.23+elementary27~ubuntu5.1.7.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.02-2ubuntu8.21+elementary26~ubuntu5.1.7.1]
shim/bionic-updates 15.4-0ubuntu9 amd64 [upgradable from: 15+1552672080.a4a1fbe-0ubuntu2]
shim-signed/bionic-updates 1.37~18.04.11+15.4-0ubuntu9 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.37~18.04.8+15+1552672080.a4a1fbe-0ubuntu2]
michael@elementaryOS-phy:/$
```

Tried "apt upgrade -f" per prior advice from Maccer at question [Packages being kept back when trying an update](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/28829/packages-being-kept-back-when-trying-an-update) :

```
michael@elementaryOS-phy:/$ sudo apt upgrade -f grub-common grub-pc grub-pc-bin grub2-common shim shim-signed
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 grub-efi-amd64-bin : Depends: grub-common (= 2.02-2ubuntu8.21+elementary26~ubuntu5.1.7.1)
 shim-signed : Depends: grub-efi-amd64-signed (>= 1.167~) but 1.93.24+elementary22~ubuntu5.1.7.1+2.02-2ubuntu8.21+elementary26~ubuntu5.1.7.1 is to be installed or
                        grub-efi-arm64-signed (>= 1.167~) but it is not installable
E: Broken packages
michael@elementaryOS-phy:/$
```

I've also tried to install grub-efi-arm64-signed:

```
$ sudo apt install -f grub-efi-arm64-signed
[sudo] password for michael:            
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package grub-efi-arm64-signed is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'grub-efi-arm64-signed' has no installation candidate
```

I'm not sure how to verify where that package should be coming from and if it's obsoleted. Below is the output of "apt-get update".

```
$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for michael:            
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease     
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease          
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease    
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease  
Hit:6 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease            
Get:7 http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter bionic InRelease [5,908 B]
Hit:8 https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-bionic InRelease
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:10 https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bionic InRelease
Hit:11 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable InRelease 
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:14 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease              
Ign:15 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic InRelease   
Hit:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Ign:17 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic Release     
Ign:18 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main amd64 Packages
Hit:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:20 http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter bionic/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [301 kB]
Ign:21 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main i386 Packages
Hit:12 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease
Hit:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/philip.scott/elementary-tweaks/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Ign:23 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main all Packages
Ign:24 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main Translation-en_US
Hit:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/timeshift/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Ign:26 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main Translation-es
Hit:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net/yunnxx/elementary/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Ign:28 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main Translation-en
Ign:29 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:30 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:31 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons
Ign:32 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:33 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons
Ign:34 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main DEP-11 128x128 Icons
Ign:35 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main all c-n-f Metadata
Ign:36 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:18 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main amd64 Packages
Ign:21 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main i386 Packages
Ign:23 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main all Packages
Ign:24 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main Translation-en_US
Ign:26 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main Translation-es
Ign:28 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main Translation-en
Ign:29 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:30 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:31 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons
Ign:32 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:33 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons
Ign:34 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main DEP-11 128x128 Icons
Ign:35 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main all c-n-f Metadata
Ign:36 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:18 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main amd64 Packages
Ign:21 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main i386 Packages
Ign:23 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main all Packages
Ign:24 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main Translation-en_US
Ign:26 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main Translation-es
Ign:28 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main Translation-en
Ign:29 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:30 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:31 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons
Ign:32 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:33 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons
Ign:34 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main DEP-11 128x128 Icons
Ign:35 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main all c-n-f Metadata
Ign:36 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Hit:18 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main amd64 Packages
Hit:21 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main i386 Packages
Ign:21 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main i386 Packages
Ign:23 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main all Packages
Ign:24 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main Translation-en_US
Ign:26 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main Translation-es
Ign:28 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main Translation-en
Ign:29 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:30 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:31 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons
Ign:32 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:33 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons
Ign:34 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main DEP-11 128x128 Icons
Ign:35 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main all c-n-f Metadata
Ign:36 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:21 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main i386 Packages
Ign:23 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main all Packages
Ign:24 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main Translation-en_US
Ign:26 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main Translation-es
Ign:28 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main Translation-en
Ign:29 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:30 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:31 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons
Ign:32 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:33 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons
Ign:34 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main DEP-11 128x128 Icons
Ign:35 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main all c-n-f Metadata
Ign:36 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:21 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main i386 Packages
Ign:23 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main all Packages
Ign:24 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main Translation-en_US
Ign:26 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main Translation-es
Ign:28 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main Translation-en
Ign:29 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:30 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:31 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons
Ign:32 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:33 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons
Ign:34 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main DEP-11 128x128 Icons
Ign:35 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main all c-n-f Metadata
Ign:36 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Hit:21 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main i386 Packages
Ign:23 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main all Packages
Ign:24 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main Translation-en_US
Ign:26 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main Translation-es
Ign:28 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main Translation-en
Ign:29 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:30 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:31 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons
Ign:32 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:33 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons
Ign:34 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main DEP-11 128x128 Icons
Ign:35 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main all c-n-f Metadata
Ign:36 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub18 bionic/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Fetched 307 kB in 25s (12.4 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
```

I'm not sure what to do next. In case it matters, my system is multi boot with Windows 10 and I think two intallations of Ubuntu. I can't recall for certain about the Ubuntus, nor the order in which I did things. I think Windows was installed first. Below is my grub menu.

```
GNU GRUBversion 2.02
*elementary
Advanced options for elementary
Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda1)
Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (20.04) (on /dev/sdb5)
Advanced options for Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (20.04) (on /dev/sdb5)
Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS(20.04) (on /dev/sdb7)
Advanced options for Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (20.04) (on /dev/sdb7)
System setup
```

Thanks for any help you can provide!
Best regards, Mike

Comment: I have the same issue. Cannot update OS with appcenter (OS elementary 5.1). When I debug the OS update I get this: ** (io.elementary.appcenter:32171): WARNING **: 15:25:26.074: Package.vala:553: Operation failed for package Aktualizacje systemu operacyjnego - WARNING: You are trying to remove the following essential packages: shim-signed grub-efi-amd64-signed (due to shim-signed) I also use WIN10 on the same disk as elementary and I use GRUB

Answer (score 0):

Any thoughts anyone? Would be great even to be pointed to another group/forum to get an answer to this question. I have searched for many hours across the web and cannot get a solid lead on how to proceed. Best I can see is that the shim-signed might be something from Microsoft for secure booting in a dual boot environment, but I cannot find anything specific on how to remedy the situation. This continues to block my OS updates.

Best, Mike

Answer (score 0):

Try to solve this by running:

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

If this doesn't help, I usually resolve by using `aptitude`:

```
sudo aptitude upgrade
```

Aptitude is usually smart enough to find proper way out.